# How to fix Python Pywinauto KeySequence Error

Tags: python, pywinauto

I'm trying to enter (Alt + Windows Key) in a script to my application.  I have defined type_keys

```
def type_keys(string, element):

    """Type a string char by char to Element window"""

    for char in string:

        element.type_keys(char)
```

Then calling it during a save here:

```
              # Save

              print("Saving")

              type_keys("%{VK_LWIN down}", win)

              #wait_win_ready(win)

              time.sleep(10)

              type_keys("1", win)

              win.wait("enabled", timeout = REFRESH_TIMEOUT)
```

I'm getting an error that seems my syntax is incorrect - but not sure how to fix.

```
Saving

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "c:\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main

    "__main__", mod_spec)

  File "c:\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code

    exec(code, run_globals)

  File "C:\Python36\Scripts\pbixrefresher.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>

  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pbixrefresher\pbixrefresher.py", line 67, in main

    type_keys("%{VK_LWIN down}", win)

  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pbixrefresher\pbixrefresher.py", line 13, in type_keys

    element.type_keys(char)

  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\base_wrapper.py", line 971, in type_keys

    vk_packet)

  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\keyboard.py", line 710, in send_keys

    vk_packet=vk_packet)

  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\keyboard.py", line 621, in parse_keys

    raise KeySequenceError('`}` not found')

pywinauto.keyboard.KeySequenceError: `}` not found
```

Hoping for some help on why I'm receiving this error!  Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typo in this line: `type_keys("%{VK_LWIN down}", win)` which should be `element.type_keys("%{VK_LWIN down}")`

The problem is that your implementation of `type_keys` unrolls the sequence to the something like this:

```
element.type_keys("%")
element.type_keys("{") # fails here, absolutely expected!
element.type_keys("V")
element.type_keys("K")
element.type_keys("_")
element.type_keys("L")
element.type_keys("W")
element.type_keys("I")
element.type_keys("N")
element.type_keys(" ") # it won't be typed without param `with_spaces=True` (default is False)
element.type_keys("d")
element.type_keys("o")
element.type_keys("w")
element.type_keys("n")
element.type_keys("}")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment - in your answer - you are saying to remove ", win" from the type_keys line - using element will still find the correct application window (in this case a pbix file that has been defined as win?) - I will test and get back here - thank you again so much.